# Best way to handle timeout / delay event?

Tags: quarkus

I would implement a timeout event in quarkus and I search the best way to do that.
Problem summary :

- I have a process who wait answer from a REST service
- If the service is call, I'll go to next process
- If the service isn't call before the delay => I must not validate the process and go to the next process

So I'm thinking of using the quarkus event bus, with a delayed message. If the message is send, I close the process and go to the next process. If the client answer before the delay, the message will never be send (how can do that?)

Thanks you

Comment: Hello, check the faulttolerance api https://quarkus.io/guides/smallrye-fault-tolerance, with this you can specify a fallback to execute when your timout is meet, so instead of using the event bus, you will just use this api for defining the timeout and providing an alternative execution when it happens, it is also possible to detec the timeout just as a normal exception and manage it in the usual way.

Comment: Hello Javier, thanks you I will take a look at fault tolerance to see if this can fit my use case